# Is there any third party apps on which we can Sign Up using microsoft account?

Tags: office365-apps

Is there any third party apps on which we can Sign Up using microsoft account?
Like for Yatra, Makemytrip, zomato, bigbasket any many other apps we can use our google account to get signed up.
Any lead will be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: This is not the right place to post it. Off-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Vivek baranwal go with firebase auth

Comment: I need already developed apps which supports sign Up using microsoft account.

Comment: @VivekBaranwal https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wizkids.appwriter&hl=en  i use microsoft login in this app

Comment: Bluemail also supports microsoft account login.